# What is the difference between these Peewee query filter forms

Tags: python-3.x, peewee

In the description of [filtering records in Peewee](http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/querying.html#filtering-records), there are examples of two alternative syntaxes: using **commas** to separate multiple conditions, such as the following example,

```
Tweet.select().where(Tweet.user == user, Tweet.is_published == True)
```

and using **bitwise operators**.  I cannot figure out (and cannot find a description of) the difference between using the comma syntax and using bitwise operators.  What does the comma syntax actually do?  From the (single) documented example of using a comma, it *seems* like it might be equivalent to using `&`, as in

```
Tweet.select().where( (Tweet.user == user) & (Tweet.is_published == True) )
```

Is that the case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, they are equivalent, as per the code:

```py
    def where(self, *expressions):
        if self._where is not None:
            expressions = (self._where,) + expressions
        self._where = reduce(operator.and_, expressions)
```